# Django when tried to Like a post, value is changing but also gives error NoReverseMatch at /something/something/

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am working on a project on django app, where user can like or dislike a post. Like and dislike buttons are working fine, also value is saved in database. But when button "Like" is clicked it shows this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /gallery/likes/ Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 9}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['gallery\\/(?P<album_id>[^/]+)$']
```

but i don't want this error.

model.py

```
class Album(models.Model):    
    caption = models.TextField()
    photo = models.FileField() 
   uploader=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.caption  

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('gallery:detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

url.py

```
app_name = 'gallery'

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
  path('<album_id>',views.detail, name='detail'),
  path('likes/',views.like_post, name='like_post'),
  path('album<pk>/delete',views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),
 ]
```

views.py

```
def detail(request,album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    is_liked = False
    if album.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
          is_liked = True
    context = {
            'album' : album,
            'is_liked' : is_liked,
    }
    return render(request, 'gallery/detail.html', context)


 def like_post(request):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, id=request.POST.get('album_id'))
    is_liked = False
   if album.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        album.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
   else:
       album.likes.add(request.user)
       is_liked = True
   return HttpResponseRedirect(album.get_absolute_url())
```

detail.html

```
{% extends 'gallery/base.html' %}
 <title>{% block title%}User Photos{% endblock %}</title>
{% block body%}  
 <div class="center">
    <img src="{{ album.photo.url }}" height="442" width="512">
     <h3>{{ album.caption }}</h3>

  {% if request.user == album.uploader %}
    <form action="{% url 'gallery:album-delete' album.id %}" method="post" >
              {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ album.id }}" />
        <button type="submit" class="deleteB">delete
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>            
    </form>
   {% endif %}

  <!--like option adding-->
    <form action="{% url 'gallery:like_post' %}" method="post" >
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" name="album_id" value="{{album.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">DisLike</button>   
         {% else %} 
            <button type="submit" name="album_id" value="{{album.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button> 
          {% endif %}        
    </form>

  </div>


{% endblock %}
```

I'm new to django so I'm unable to understand what's the main error here. I think url.py should be updated. Version of the django is 2.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path uses `album_id`.

```
path('<album_id>',views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Therefore you must use `album_id` in your `get_absolute_url` method if you use `kwargs`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('gallery:detail', kwargs={"album_id": self.pk})
```

Your URL patterns are a bit fragile. At the moment, `'likes/'` is almost matched by `'<album_id>'`, which would cause requests to be handled by the URL. It would be safer to move `'likes/'` above the detail pattern, so that it is matched first.
Since album_id is an integer, you can use `<int:album_id>` so that it only matches digits. If you use a trailing slash in `likes/`, I would add it to the `detail` path as well to be consistent.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('likes/',views.like_post, name='like_post'),
    path('<int:album_id>/',views.detail, name='detail'),
    ...
]
```